# Render taglib from markup grails

Tags: grails, gsp

Inside my controller I have an action with this return:

```
 render {
        li {
            input(name:'question'+questNumber)
            remoteLink(action: 'addResponseToQuest',onsuccess:'logTestData(data)',"Link")
        }
    }
```

The list element is correctly rendered, but the remotelink no.

How can I use render the same result as  tag?

With encodeAsHTML() nothing happens.

Thanks in advance

Luis

Comment: What does get rendered (and what were you expecting)?

Comment: Render nothing. I want the complete <a> etc etc with ajax request. If I try to send on output as text (out << remoteLink(action: 'addResponseToQuest'[...]) I see the html string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix your tags with `mkp.yieldUnescaped`, e.g.:

```
render {
    li {
        input(name:'question'+questNumber)
        mkp.yieldUnescaped remoteLink(action: 'addResponseToQuest',onsuccess:'logTestData(data)',"Link")
    }
}
```

The `render` closure is an instance of a Groovy [MarkupBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html), see its docs for explanation.